# How to disable Read-Only routing in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups

I know I can just change the connection string to remove the `applicationintent` property, but how do I remove the configuration from within SQL Server?

For example, if we query `sys.availability_read_only_routing_lists`, how do I get an empty result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ref:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-availability-group-transact-sql

Use `ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP` command with `MODIFY REPLICA ON` option.

```
<modify_replica_spec>::=  
  <server_instance> WITH  
    (    
       ENDPOINT_URL = 'TCP://system-address:port'   
     | AVAILABILITY_MODE = { SYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT | ASYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT }   
     | FAILOVER_MODE = { AUTOMATIC | MANUAL }   
     | SEEDING_MODE = { AUTOMATIC | MANUAL }   
     | BACKUP_PRIORITY = n  
     | SECONDARY_ROLE ( {   
          ALLOW_CONNECTIONS = { NO | READ_ONLY | ALL }   
        | READ_ONLY_ROUTING_URL = 'TCP://system-address:port'   
          } )  
     | PRIMARY_ROLE ( {   
          ALLOW_CONNECTIONS = { READ_WRITE | ALL }   
        | READ_ONLY_ROUTING_LIST = { ( ‘<server_instance>’ [ ,...n ] ) | NONE }   
          } )  
     | SESSION_TIMEOUT = seconds  
    )
```

> NONE
>
> Specifies that when this availability replica is the primary
>   replica, read-only routing will not be supported. This is the default
>   behavior. When used with MODIFY REPLICA ON, this value disables an
>   existing list, if any.

Comment: Great solution, thanks for information. Want to ask though, are there any consequences to disabling readability on the secondaries?

Comment: Unless you have any good reason I would not do that. You are sending all traffic to one node.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the "readable secondary" property of each replica under Availability Group properties. You need to connect to the primary in ssms, then right click availability group and select properties. See the third screen in this blog post: https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-configure-read-only-routing-for-an-availability-group-in-sql-server-2016/. Your choices are "Yes", "Read Intent", and "No".